# json method not found when Deserializing a request response

Tags: json, rust, json-deserialization, serde, reqwest

I'm pretty new to Rust, and I just cannot seem to find the solution to this problem. I am trying to get the response of the get request as json.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate reqwest;
use reqwest::Error;

fn main(){
    #[derive(Deserialize)]

struct Ip {
    origin: String,
}

let json: Ip = reqwest::get("http://httpbin.org/ip").json();
//reqwest::get("http://httpbin.org/ip")?.json()?;
}
```

Here is cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
serde_derive = "1.0"
reqwest = { version = "0.10", features = ["blocking"] }
```

The error I keep getting is 
[image: json error]

Also,
if i use

```
reqwest::get("http://httpbin.org/ip")?.json()?;
```

(Adding the question marks)
I get another error saying

```
cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`
this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
```

How do i fix these?

Comment: Please include the text of the error you get rather than a screenshot.

Comment: Please make a proper [mre]. Indicating the specific version of `reqwest` is likely to be important here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per the [doc](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.4/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.json), you need to enable the `json` reqwest feature in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
reqwest = { version = "0.10", features = ["blocking", "json"] }
```

Also, [`reqwest::get`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.4/reqwest/fn.get.html) is part of the `async` API. Since your `main` is synchronous, you want [`reqwest::blocking::get`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.10.4/reqwest/blocking/fn.get.html)

Comment: See edited answer: you probably want `reqwest::blocking::get` instead of `reqwest::get`

Comment: Which error? Your question contains two error messages. My answer should fix the first one, the second one is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+cannot+use+the+%60%3F%60+operator+in+a+function+that+returns).